# Is this correct to access parent class like this?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to use subclassing in c++.

I has some questions on using this.

1. How to call parent's initProcess method?
2. How to print parent's instance address?

===================== Following is ClassA (parent class) ===========================

```
   class ClassA 
    {
    public:
        ClassA();
        ~ClassA();
        void ClassA::initProcess();
    };

    ClassA::ClassA(){}
    ClassA::~ClassA(){}

    void ClassA::initProcess()
    {
    }
```

================= Following is ClassB of ClassA's subclass ================

```
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();

    void ClassB::initProcess();
};

ClassB::ClassB(){}
ClassB::~ClassB(){}

void ClassB::initProcess()
{
    ClassA::initProcess();  // <-- Is this correct to access ClassB's parent method?
    printf("ClassA is : %d", ClassA???); // <-- How to print parent's instance (ClassA) address?
}
```

Comment: The instance of ClassA is the instance of ClassB, printf("ClassA is : %X", this);

Comment: The function should really be declared `virtual` if it's intended to be overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ClassA::initProcess();  // <-- Is this correct to access ClassB's
>   parent method?

Yes, that is the right way to invoke the base class method `initProcess()`.

> ```
> printf("ClassA is : %d", ClassA???); // <-- How to print parent's instance (ClassA) address?
> ```

I believe that line of code should be something like:

`printf("ClassA is : %p", dynamic_cast<ClassA*>(this));`

However, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I distinguish instances using instance's address. </br>

I'd like to print child's address and parent's address.

Comment: Using the address to distinguish between base class and derived class instances doesn't feel right. You could make the method `initProcess()` virtual and use polymorphism if you'd like to have different behaviour for base and derived classes. Also, as @Bart van Nierop pointed out, the address will return the same value for both. In other words, Is there a particular reason why you *must* this?

Comment: There is no difference between the address of the child and the parent. It's the same instance. See http://ideone.com/PEpCxp.

Comment: Thanks Bhargav and Bart.

Comment: Your answer helped for me. ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassA::initProcess();  // <-- Is this correct to access ClassB's parent method?
```

That is the correct way to call the base class.

> How to print parent's instance (ClassA) address?

The instance of the base class *is* the instance of the subclass. Here's some working code to illustrate this.

```
#include <cstdio>

class ClassA 
    {
    public:
        ClassA();
        ~ClassA();
        void initProcess();
    };

ClassA::ClassA(){}
ClassA::~ClassA(){}

void ClassA::initProcess()
{
    printf("Class A address: %d\n", dynamic_cast<ClassA*>(this));
}

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();

    void initProcess();
};

ClassB::ClassB(){}
ClassB::~ClassB(){}

void ClassB::initProcess()
{
    ClassA::initProcess(); 
    printf("Class B address: %d\n", this);
}

int main()
{
    ClassB b;
    b.initProcess();
    return 0;
}
```

[See this code in action](http://ideone.com/jgTJTX)